# API-Platform - How to update and embedded relation and persist it's id's

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have two entities,

`Quote` and `QuoteProduct` with a `OneToMany` Relation between.

When I perform a PUT request to update the embedded QuoteProduct relation, it always remove all items and add them, which result to generate new id's.

According to the official doc, https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#denormalization
I should be able to update a specific item by passing his id

**Quote Entity**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;


/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"quote.read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"quote.write"}},
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={"access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')", "access_control_message"="You do not have the permission to get"},
 *         "post"={"access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_COMMERCIAL')", "access_control_message"="You do not have the permission to add"}
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "put"={"access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_COMMERCIAL')", "access_control_message"="You do not have the permission to update"},
 *         "delete"={"access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_COMMERCIAL')", "access_control_message"="You do not have the permission to delete."}
 *     },
 *     attributes={"force_eager"=false}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`quotes`")
 */
class Quote
{


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = Uuid::uuid4();
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
     */
    private $id;



    /**
     * @var Collection|QuoteProduct[]
     *
     * @Groups({"quote.read", "quote.write"})
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\QuoteProduct", mappedBy="quote", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"code" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $products;




    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* ----------------------------------------GETTER AND SETTER------------------------------------- */
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @return Collection|QuoteProduct[]
     */
    public function getProducts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * @param QuoteProduct $product
     * @return Quote
     */
    public function addProduct(QuoteProduct $product): self
    {
        if(false === $this->products->contains($product))
        {
            $product->setQuote($this);
            $this->products->add($product);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param QuoteProduct $product
     * @return Quote
     */
    public function removeProduct(QuoteProduct $product)
    {
        if(!$this->products->contains($product))
        {
            return;
        }
        $this->products->removeElement($product);
        $product->setQuote(null);
    }



}

?>
```

**QuoteProduct Entity**

```
<?php


namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;


/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"quote-product.read"},"enable_max_depth"=true},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"quote-product.write"},"enable_max_depth"=true},
 *     attributes={"force_eager"=false}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`quote_products`")
 */
class QuoteProduct
{

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"quote-product.read", "quote-product.write", "quote.read", "quote.write"})
     *
     */
    private $code;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Quote", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="products")
     * @Assert\Valid
     * @Groups({"quote-product.read", "quote-product.write", "quote.read", "quote.write"})
     */
    private $quote;




    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* ----------------------------------------GETTER AND SETTER------------------------------------- */
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = Uuid::uuid4();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }





    
    public function getQuote(): ?Quote
    {
        return $this->quote;
    }

    public function setQuote(?Quote $quote)
    {
        $this->quote = $quote;

        return $this;
    }


   

    public function getCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode(?string $code): self
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    
}
```

Get request to quotes/fbe01952-2a23-4882-bb9f-970e8598f979

Result:

```
{
  "@context": "\/contexts\/Quote",
  "@id": "\/quotes\/fbe01952-2a23-4882-bb9f-970e8598f979",
  "@type": "Quote",
  "products": [
    {
      "@id": "\/quote_products\/15216edd-dd5c-49d5-bf3f-39d389d804d6",
      "@type": "QuoteProduct",
      "code": "Code 1",
      "quote": "\/quotes\/fbe01952-2a23-4882-bb9f-970e8598f979"
    }
  ]
}
```

Put request to quotes/fbe01952-2a23-4882-bb9f-970e8598f979
with JSON params (please note that I changed the value of QuoteProduct code property)

```
{
  "@context": "\/contexts\/Quote",
  "@id": "\/quotes\/fbe01952-2a23-4882-bb9f-970e8598f979",
  "@type": "Quote",
  "products": [
    {
      "@id": "\/quote_products\/15216edd-dd5c-49d5-bf3f-39d389d804d6",
      "@type": "QuoteProduct",
      "code": "A new code",
      "quote": "\/quotes\/fbe01952-2a23-4882-bb9f-970e8598f979"
    }
  ]
}
```

Resulting to :

```
{
  "@context": "\/contexts\/Quote",
  "@id": "\/quotes\/fbe01952-2a23-4882-bb9f-970e8598f979",
  "@type": "Quote",
  "products": [
    {
      "@id": "\/quote_products\/865da321-dd74-4a39-82a3-e0e935555262",
      "@type": "QuoteProduct",
      "code": "A new code",
      "quote": "\/quotes\/fbe01952-2a23-4882-bb9f-970e8598f979"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code has changed has expected but it generated a new @id.

Comment: The creation of a new `uuid` on the constructor seems suspect. I think that might be the reason you are getting a new identifier each time. Doctrine won't call your constructors, but Api-Platform will.

Comment: @yivi yes i was suspecting this too but after several test it was not comming from the constructor

Answer (score -4):

After hours and hours i manage to find the answer , i was posting my request with params :

`Content-Type : application/json;charset=UTF-8`

When i use `Content-Type : application/ld+json` it is working as expected

According to API platform doc , https://api-platform.com/docs/core/content-negotiation/ this is making sense : *Using the raw JSON or raw XML formats is discouraged, prefer using JSON-LD instead, which provides more feature and is as easy to use.*

Comment: That isn't answer, yes different content behaves differently. Only json+ld supports patch, so according to RESTful specs, when you post or put, you need to send whole resource. That is because caching takes care of invalidating outdated objects. One can argue for concurrency problems and solution to that is one should implement CQS, CQRS or DDD patterns to leverage both Restfulness and tackle updating separately as stated by those design patterns. This allows various clients to negotiate content types and can perform same operations regardless what communication protocol they use.